# why my blazor webassembly only have installable icon/pop up on chrome but not in opera or firefox

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

i cant figure out why the pop up/icon for installation only visible in chrome. when i open my blazor webassembly using firefox or opera. i dont get icon or notification to install the app.

is Blazor Web Assembly only installable thru chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Currently progressive web apps' features are only "fully" supported by certain browsers such as Chrome, Safari, Firefox for Android and Microsoft Edge, but not by Opera nor Firefox for desktop, that's why you can't install your application.